# No default label for attribute in zend form

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework

I have very strange problem. I'm creating form radio element using Zend_Form class and by default it should be wrapped in  attribute and it is, but it have no for attribute that points on particular radio element. Why? It should be by default. Did i turn sth off or what?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. What do you mean when you say "by default it should be wrapped in attribute"?

Answer (score 0):

The `for` attribute is not required on labels if the label *contains* the form element it relates to, as is the case with ZF1's radio buttons. This behaviour is hard-coded into the `formRadio` view helper so it would be difficult (although not impossible) to override.

If you could explain why you need the attribute in particular I might be able to help further.

Comment: i use some rating plugin, and i click on star i want to rate (input radio) and without label for i click alvays in the same star (first) . It worked correctly in zend 1.11.11. But in 1.12 something changed and its not. I use it in plenty places so i would ilke to resolve it on decorator level.